# Typescript - How to declare anonymous object with known properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In JS, a lot of my modules are just objects that wrap static functions, enums and properties. For example, I've got a module `Debug` which is similar to this (I really simplified it):

```
export default Debug = {
    // Current mode set, enum value from Modes. Setted outside of the module (see below).
    mode : null,

    // Enum of all possible modes
    Modes : {
        DEV : 0,
        PROD : 1,
    },

    // getter, checks if it's in production mode
    get isInProdMode() {
        return Debug.mode === Debug.Modes.PROD;
    },

    // If the condition is met, it will throw an error in development mode, or just silently log a warning in production mode
    assert : function(condition, message){
        if (condiftion) {
            if (Debug.isInProdMode)
                console.warn(message);
            else
                throw message;
        }
    }
}

// index.js
Debug.mode = Debug.Modes.DEV;
```

How can I make an anonymous object like this in Typescript? With an Enum as property? And a getter function? All properties are known.
I'm really stuck.

Comment: this code is already valid typescript. What else would you need it to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I've tended to resolve these scenarios is to just make interfaces for the properties of the anonymous objects, and then interfaces for the anonymous objects:

```
enum Modes {
    DEV     = 0,
    PROD    = 1,
}

interface IDebug {
    mode: Modes | null;
    Modes: typeof Modes;
    readonly isInProdMode: boolean;
    assert: (condition: boolean, message: string) => void;
}

const Debug: IDebug = {
    mode: null,
    Modes,
    get isInProdMode() {
        return Debug.mode === Debug.Modes.PROD;
    },
    assert: (condition, message) => {
        if (condition) {
            if (Debug.isInProdMode) {
                console.warn(message);
            } else {
                throw message;
            }
        }
    },
};

export default Debug;
```

Comment: `const Debug: IDebug = {
        Modes,
        // ...
     }`
I would never think this possible. Ô.Ô

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the idiomatic way would be to use namespaces.

```
namespace Debug {
  export enum Modes { DEV, PROD }

  export var mode: Modes = Modes.DEV;

  export function isInProdMode(): boolean {
    return mode === Modes.PROD;
  }

  export function assert(condition: boolean, message: string) {
    if (condition) {
      if (isInProdMode()) {
        console.warn(message);
      } else {
        throw message;
      }
    }
  }
} 

export default Debug
```

However, namespaces don't support getters and setters, so that getter would need to be converted into a regular function.

If you need to declare this code as an object, then you could define the enum first, then reference in from the object.

```
enum Modes { DEV, PROD }

const Debug = {
  mode: Modes = Modes.DEV,
  get isInProdMode(): boolean {
    return Debug.mode === Modes.PROD;
  },
  assert(condition: boolean, message: string) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Please stop using TypeScript namespaces. They prevent you from using ES6 Module imports. It is time to leave that sad piece of history behind!

Comment: @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen It sounds like you're getting mixed up with named exports vs default exports and blaming it on namespaces. A default export object shares all the same problems as a default export namespace.

Comment: Or if you're sure, feel free to go read the source for the TypeScript compiler, which makes heavy use of namespaces as a feature and tell them to leave it behind. They're still an important construct for creating scoped types.

Comment: I am talking about being able to use `import { someStuff } from './some-es6-module';`. If you know how to do that in a file with a namespace, please let me know. The same goes for accessing exported members of a namespace from an ES6 Module.

Comment: That's a named export, which isn't possible with objects or namespaces if you are using `export default` like OP.

Comment: So if we have `export default namespace Debug { // ... }` or even just `export namespace Debug { // ... }` we can't reference it from an ES6 module or reference an ES6 module from the file containing the namespace, is that right?

Comment: Yeah, of course. `import Debug from "..."` or `import { Debug } from  "..."`. Namespaces compile down into IIFEs that return objects.

Comment: Thanks. I am working with some legacy code is written exclusively with namespaces and I just can't seem to make it work with ES6 Modules and NPM Packages. `export default namespace Debug { // ... }` does not seem to be valid.

Comment: You can do `namespace Debug { ... } export default Debug`.

Comment: For the same reason you can't do `export default const Debug = { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Nested namespaces are still a pain. I am deprecating them in the codebase and converting to ES6 Modules where possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
// index.js
import Debug from './debug';

Debug.mode = Debug.Modes.DEV;
console.log(Debug.isInProdMode);
// false
```

Comment: My question was about converting the Debug module.

Comment: Excuse me, I seem to have missed your point. What do you mean by *converting* it?

Comment: For instance, make `Modes`an enum. Or add a signature to the `assert` function. I didn't manage to do it because it was in a anonymous object, not in a class declaration. But I got the answer from @pete. Thanks.